# Adding column from one file based on matched column from another file in bash

Tags: bash

I have a huge text `File_1` with 8 columns. I have another text `File_2` with 3 columns. Both files have an `CHROM` column and an `ID` column that match between files. Meaning that these two columns can be matched between both data files. `File_1` can have multiple rows with the same `ID`, while `File_2` only have the `ID` strings occuring once. Now I want to add the third column (`ALT_CTS`) of `File 2` to the `File_1` every time it matches with the ID column. Since the `ID`'s in `File_1` can be occurring multiple times it can well be that the values from `ALT_CTS` are added more than once to `File_1`.
I have also added an example of an expected output file.

File_1:

```
filename CHROM ID A1_CASE_CT A1_CTRL_CT CASE_ALLELE_CT CTRL_ALLELE_CT OBS_CT
1008_H 1 rs3131972 27 142 136 766 451
1008_H 1 rs3131962 24 115 136 764 450
1008_H 1 rs12562034 16 68 136 766 451
1008_H 1 rs12131377 10 49 136 758 447
1008_H 1 rs61768212 19 98 136 762 449
1008_H 2 rs11240779 38 184 136 764 450
1008_H 1 rs57181708 19 71 134 764 449
1008_H 1 rs4970383 36 186 136 762 449
1008_H 1 rs4970382 59 293 136 764 450
904_V 1 rs3131962 3 54 34 868 451
904_V 13 rs9599776 5 175 34 862 448
904_V 1 rs3131972 3 51 34 864 449
904_V 13 rs11240 14 295 34 866 450
904_V 13 rs58914154 7 189 34 862 448
904_V 1 rs57181708 16 365 34 860 447
904_V 13 rs9572677 10 325 34 862 448
904_V 2 rs11240779 0 48 34 868 451
904_V 13 rs12853559 2 105 34 868 451
```

File_2:

```
CHROM ID ALT_CTS
1 rs3131972 162
1 rs3131962 131
1 rs12562034 93
1 rs12131377 75
1 rs61768212 125
2 rs11240779 229
1 rs57181708 100
1 rs4970383 240
1 rs4970382 423
13 rs9599776 182
1 rs13303222 197
1 rs6657440 400
1 rs4970459 207
1 rs74047407 222
1 rs57181708 290
1 rs2272757 369
1 rs35471880 57
13 rs12853559 369
1 rs13303010 99
1 rs6696971 51
1 rs6696609 268
```

Expected output file:

```
filename CHROM ID A1_CASE_CT A1_CTRL_CT CASE_ALLELE_CT CTRL_ALLELE_CT OBS_CT ALT_CTS
1008_H 1 rs3131972 27 142 136 766 451 162
1008_H 1 rs3131962 24 115 136 764 450 131
1008_H 1 rs12562034 16 68 136 766 451 93
1008_H 1 rs12131377 10 49 136 758 447 75
1008_H 1 rs61768212 19 98 136 762 449 125
1008_H 2 rs11240779 38 184 136 764 450 229
1008_H 1 rs57181708 19 71 134 764 449 100
1008_H 1 rs4970383 36 186 136 762 449 240
1008_H 1 rs4970382 59 293 136 764 450 423
904_V 1 rs3131962 3 54 34 868 451 131 
904_V 13 rs9599776 5 175 34 862 448 182
904_V 1 rs3131972 3 51 34 864 449 162
904_V 13 rs11240 14 295 34 866 450 NA
904_V 13 rs58914154 7 189 34 862 448 NA
904_V 1 rs57181708 16 365 34 860 447 290
904_V 13 rs9572677 10 325 34 862 448 NA
904_V 2 rs11240779 0 48 34 868 451 229
904_V 13 rs12853559 2 105 34 868 451 369
```

I tried this code, but unfortunately it doesn't work well, since nothing is added. It gives me File_1 as output.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3;next}{print $0,a[$2]}' File_2 file_1
```

Comment: You need to use `$3` to extract `ID` in File_1. Please try `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$3;next}{print $0,a[$3]}' File_2 File_1`.

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot. Sorry for the blindness.